# How do I prevent an implicit cast double -> int?

Tags: c++, casting

Question as above, more details below:

I have a class `Money` to deal with... well, you guessed what. I am very strict about not allowing `Money` and `double` to interact(*), so the following code is **not** possible:

```
Money m1( 4.50 );
double d = 1.5;
Money m2 = m1 * d; // <-- compiler error
```

Now I'm thinking about allowing multiplication of `Money` with `int`, as in "you have 6 pieces of cake for $4.50 each (so go and find cheaper cake somewhere)."

```
class Money
{
    Money();
    Money( const Money & other );
    explicit Money( double d );
    ...
    Money & operator*=( int i );
    ...
}
inline const Money operator*( const Money & m, int i ) { return Money( m ) *= i; }
inline const Money operator*( int i, const Money & m ) { return Money( m ) *= i; }
```

That works fine, **but**...
unfortunately, C++ does *implicit casts* from `double` to `int`, so suddenly my first code snippet will compile. I don't want that. Is there any way to prevent *implicit casts* in this situation?

Thanks! -- Robin

(*) Reason: I have lot's of legacy code that handles all `Money`-related stuff with `double`, and I don't want those types confused until everything run with `Money`.

Edit: Added constructors for Money.

Edit: Thanks, everyone, for your answers. Almost all of them were great and helpful. R. Martinho Fernandes' comment "you can do `inline const Money operator*( const Money & m, double d ) = delete;`" was actually the answer (as soon as I switch to a C++11-supporting compiler). Kerrek SB gave a good none-C++11 alternative, but what I ended up with using is actually Nicola Musatti's "overload `long`" approach. That's why I'm flagging his answer as "the answer" (also because all the useful ideas came up as comments to his answer). Again, thanks!

Comment: I have changed your reference of `C` to `C++` in the text.

Comment: But, as thought by mloskot, there could be an implicit conversion double -> Money

Comment: What compiler are you using? It should at least warn you about converting from double to int. Sounds strange.

Comment: @mloskot, xanatos: Done. I'm using explicit Money( double ), so no problem there.

Comment: @vz0 VisualStudio 2010. Doesn't warn about a lot of things, unfortunately.

Comment: @Robin: even with `/W4` ? It used to warn about everything at that level on my toy examples :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a declaration for a private overload of your augmented assignment operator:

```
private:
  Money & operator*=( double i );
```

Comment: Or even make it a template with an `is_same` or `is_integral` check!

Comment: That only works for using `Money m *= d;`. But how would I hide the (external/global) operators `inline const Money operator*( const Money & m, double d )` and `inline const Money operator*( double d, const Money & m )`. No way to set `private` there, is it?

Comment: @Robin: in C++11 you can do `inline const Money operator*( const Money & m, double d ) = delete;`. If your compiler supports this, use it!

Comment: @R.Martinho: Great! MSVC2010 does not support this, but still, this is actually THE answer I was looking for!

Comment: @Robin: An alternative approach would be to introduce an overload for `long`. If I'm not mistaken this would make all implicit conversions ambiguous.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, because the additional overload is only there to block implicit conversions. On the other hand, given that you cannot use `delete`, I'd say that this combined with an explanatory comment would result in a clearer way to express your intent than any template meta-programming based approach. Unless your code is meant for Boost, that is ;-)

Answer (score 15):

How about a template plus compile-time trait check:

```
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template <typename T>
Money & operator*=(const T & n)
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Error: can only multiply money by integral amounts!");
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Only problem is: Now I get compiler errors, but I get them in money.h, not where I use the forbitten operators. So `delete` or `enable_if` may be even better. (Or just switching to a C++11 compatible compiler, if not for company rules...)

Comment: @Robin: when an error occurs during template instantiation (which is the case here) the compiler should give you the instantiation stack, and the bottom entry in the stack would be the file and line where the operator was actually called.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of two ways to provide this:

- either using template and "concept" checks
- or using "forbidden" overloads

---

Using overloads is the C++11 solution. C++11 introduces the `delete`  keyword especially for your case!

```
Money& operator*=(int i);
Money& operator*=(float f) = delete;

Money operator*(Money m, int i) { return m*i; }
Money operator*(Money m, float f) = delete;

Money operator*(int i, Money m) { return m*i; }
Money operator*(float f, Money m) = delete;
```

The old way (C++03) to go about that was double:

- in the class, declare the method `private`
- don't define the method and wait for the linker to complain

The second is a safeguard in the class method case, and the only way in the free-method case. It's sad that it's only detected at link-time... and the `delete` keyword is just much nicer ;)

---

Using template is another solution. You may use either `std::enable_if` or `static_assert`: one will remove the function from the overload set (SFINAE) while the other will make instantiation fail (compiler error).

Example:

```
// For enable_if
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, Money&> operator*=(T t);

template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, Money> operator*(Money m, T t);

template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, Money> operator*(T t, Money m);
```

The examples for `static_assert` are more natural (it just like a regular assert, really).

---

I would rather recommend the overload + `delete` if you have it. If you don't then a fallback to the template case is probably the best solution, because it's easier to correct compiler errors than linker ones.

Comment: Thanks, you basically summarized the other answers, plus added `enable_if` which looks interesting (`delete` doesn't work with MSVC2010, `static_assert` produces compiler error in Money, not where I use the operator). However, I can't get you're code `enable_if` example to work. The code looks good, so my fear is that `enable_if` is another C++11 feature that MSVC2010 doesn't support...

Comment: @Robin: which `enable_if` are you using ? FYI there is a slight difference of interface between `std::enable_if` and `boost::enable_if`, `std::enable_if` is equivalent to `boost::enable_if_c`. The Boost solution works in C++03 and C++11, and the std solution just pillaged it, since there is no new functionality required it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a small number holder type which had all the properties you wanted, then use that to interface with other types, such as `Money`.