# Disabling Implicit Casting in c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to disable implicit casting in C/C++.

Suppose I want to write a validity function that makes me enter only `integers in range [1,10]`

I have written:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int var=0;
    cout << "Enter a number (Integer between 1 to 10) : ";

    while( (!(cin >> var )) || (var > 10 ) || (var < 1) )
    {
        cout << "U nuts .. It can only be [1,10]\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Enter a number (Integer between 1 to 10) : ";
        }

    cout << "\nYou entered : " << var;

   return 0;
}
```

But if the user enters 9.5 it accepts it by converting the float 9.5 as 9 and storing it in var. I want any float entry to be treated as invalid entry. How do I achieve this most compactly.

I do not want to do something of this sort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    float var=0;
    cout << "Enter a number (Integer between 1 to 10) : ";

    while( (!(cin >> var )) ||(var < 1)|| (var > 10 ) || !(ceilf(var) == var) )
    {
        cout << "U nuts .. It can only be [1,10]\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Enter a number (Integer between 1 to 10) : ";
        }

    cout << "\nYou entered : " << var;

   return 0;
}
```

This serves my purpose . But what I want to know, that is there any way where a conversion from float to int - I can suppress or it can show it as false input.

Similar to the way `cin >> var` where var type is `int` - if we enter `char` it returns false condition. Can we achieve the same for `float` entry ?

Thanks

Comment: `while( (!(cin >> var )` what do you think this is doing? checking if var is 0 or not or if cin is null or not?. this will always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Koushik - if u enter 'char' then 'cin >> var' returns false as var is of type - int.

Comment: Read a string and do your own conversion.

Comment: Gaurav See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903083/how-do-i-prevent-an-implicit-cast-double-int), it talks about preventing `double` to `int` implicit conversion

Comment: For checking floating point number entries.. this may get handy.. http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/71064-checking-floating-point-number.html

Comment: cin >> var' returns false? how is that? `>>` is overloaded for istream and it return `istream&`. if you enter char its converted to int(implicitly and stored in var).

Comment: @Koushik dude .. check this out .. u got confusion with I/O Stream Class ... http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: @Koushik He means if you enter the string "char", not a `char` value. Then yes, the fail bit will be set and the stream, when converted to `bool`, will be `false`.

Comment: @sftrabbit, He is confused as to how the implicit conversion of `istream&` to `boolean` takes place. In his estimation, the ASCII value of  `char` will be stored

Comment: @sftrabbit if you enter any character - suppose I enter `'j'` or `'hello'` - then for expression `'cin >> var'` fail bit will be set for returned `istream&` - and it evalutes to `false` as `var` type is `int`

Comment: @Koushik Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-as-a-condition) too

Comment: @SuvP is there a conversion operator (operator bool()?)defined for istream?

Comment: @SuvP the conversion is not implicit but through conversion operator. and yes i was really confused about accepting char. i thought since char is integral type it will be promoted to int and stored. but wow learnt. Gaurav thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Koushik in C++11 yes there is an `operator bool()`, in C++98 there is an `operator void*` that is compared to `null` in a boolean expression.

Comment: @zakinster how is the call resolved to void * coversion operator in pre c++11 era?

Comment: @Koushik Because it's the only implicit conversion that would make the object type valid in this context. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277678/stream-output-and-implicit-void-cast-operator-function-invocation

Comment: @zakinster ah now its not required:-)

Comment: @Koushik. Yeps. I was searchin for a nice link . But I guess its all cleared now :)

Comment: @SuvP i never realised istream having conversion operator thats why the whole mess. better late than never. thanks a lot:-) .

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "implicit casting". A **cast** is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**. An **implicit conversion** is a conversion that the compiler does without a cast; an **explicit conversion** is one that the compiler does because of a cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if the user enters 9.5 it accepts it by converting the float 9.5 as 9 and storing it in var.

No it doesn't. If the the user enters `9.5`, then `cin >> var` stops reading when it hits the `.` (and leaves it on the stream). There's no float-to-int conversion because you haven't read a `float`, just an `int`.

The fix is to read the rest of the input (after `cin >> var`), and make sure there's nothing bad left over after the end of the `int`.

Comment: What is the best way to check the residual characters in cin stream ? Is there any function available to check residual? Also `cin` always confuses me - suppose it is taking an string entry.. when we hit `enter` does it remain in the stream or extracted and saved in string var `str` for expressions such as `cin >> str`

Comment: @GauravK could try [cin.ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after you read to var.

Comment: added to previous comment : What I mean to ask - `string str; cin >> str` now I enter `hello` followed by hitting `enter` - does this `enter` remain in the stream or it is also saved to `str` along with `hello`

Comment: @Koushik ignore will discard residuals , I wana check if any residual is there or not ? as explained in the answer - when we enter `9.5` , `.5` will remain in the cin stream - is there any method to check residual in istream class object?

Comment: @GauravK: the best way is `string str; readline(cin, str);`. In the case where the user enters `9` that will read an empty string, whereas `cin >> str` would read the next line.

Comment: @SteveJessop can you please give an example ?

Comment: @Gaurav `9.5` would be left in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate all of the input, you will have to get the whole line first.

Try:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line); // gets whole line
char *endptr;
long int var = strtol(line.c_str(), &endptr, 10); // converts string to int

// now check that endptr points to end of the string
if (endptr<line.c_str()+line.length()) {
  // extra characters found after the integer
}
```

Comment: This depends on the desired behaviour, and I am not in a position to determine that. The OP will be most qualified in determining the tweaks necessary, and it is not difficult to achieve this, so I will not add this behaviour to the answer.